# What is the minimal cluster config file in Ray for a laptop/dev machine?

Tags: ray

A lot of ray commands require a CLUSTER_CONFIG file.

for example

```
Usage: ray get-head-ip [OPTIONS] CLUSTER_CONFIG_FILE

Options:
  -n, --cluster-name TEXT  Override the configured cluster name.
  --help                   Show this message and exit.
```

The example files provided are big and scary.. like..

```
cluster_name: default
min_workers: 0
max_workers: 0
docker:
    image: ""
    container_name: ""
target_utilization_fraction: 0.8
idle_timeout_minutes: 5
provider:
    type: local
    head_ip: YOUR_HEAD_NODE_HOSTNAME
    worker_ips: []
auth:
    ssh_user: YOUR_USERNAME
    ssh_private_key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
head_node: {}
worker_nodes: {}
file_mounts:
     "/tmp/ray_sha": "/YOUR/LOCAL/RAY/REPO/.git/refs/heads/YOUR_BRANCH"
setup_commands: []
head_setup_commands: []
worker_setup_commands: []
setup_commands:
    - source activate ray && test -e ray || git clone https://github.com/YOUR_GITHUB/ray.git
    - source activate ray && cd ray && git fetch && git reset --hard `cat /tmp/ray_sha`
#    - source activate ray && cd ray/python && pip install -e .
head_start_ray_commands:
    - source activate ray && ray stop
    - source activate ray && ulimit -c unlimited && ray start --head --redis-port=6379 --autoscaling-config=~/ray_bootstrap_config.yaml
worker_start_ray_commands:
    - source activate ray && ray stop
    - source activate ray && ray start --redis-address=$RAY_HEAD_IP:6379
```

Say I already have a ray cluster up and running, and just want to do things like, submit a job to it using ray command line.  Do I really need all that stuff, or is there a minimal config I can use.

Comment: Here's a minimal example https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/autoscaler/aws/example-minimal.yaml. In the more verbose examples, the defaults should be good so you shouldn't need to change very much. Also, if you *already* have a Ray cluster running and you started it with the autoscaler, you can submit jobs via `ray exec`, see https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#ray-exec. See https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/ci/long_running_tests/start_workloads.sh for an example of how to use it.

Comment: Hey Robert, put your answers in the answer section so I can mark them correct and stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [minimal example](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/autoscaler/aws/example-minimal.yaml).

In the more verbose examples, the defaults should be good so you shouldn't need to change very much.

Also, if you already have a Ray cluster running and you started it with the autoscaler, you can submit jobs via `ray exec`, see [the relevant documentation](http://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#ray-exec). See [this script](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/ci/long_running_tests/start_workloads.sh) for an example of how to use it.

Comment: the bottom 2 links are broken